# javascript date of last day of previous month

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have 3 variables like this:

```
var Month = 8; // in reality, it's a parameter provided by some user input
var Year = 2011; // same here
var FirstDay = new Date(Year, Month, 1);
```

Now I want to have the value of the day before the first day of the month in a variable. I'm doing this:

```
var LastDayPrevMonth = (FirstDay.getDate() - 1);
```

It's not working as planned. What the right of doing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var LastDayPrevMonth = new Date(Year, Month, 0).getDate();
```

Comment: Then just remove the `.getDate()`. getDate returns the day of the month. It looked like that was what you wanted in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var LastDayPrevMonth = new Date(FirstDay);
LastDayPrevMonth.setHours(FirstDay.getHours()-24);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `Date` object and pass it the other date coerced to the number of milliseconds since the [Unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and then minus a whole day (in milliseconds).

```
var LastDayPrevMonth = new Date(FirstDay - 864e5);
```

**Example:**

```js
var Month = 8; // in reality, it's a parameter provided by some user input
var Year = 2011; // same here
var FirstDay = new Date(Year, Month, 1);

var LastDayPrevMonth = new Date(FirstDay - 864e5);

document.body.innerHTML = LastDayPrevMonth;
```

Comment: Does what it says. I removed the plus sign. What's the constant equal to? Seconds in a day?

Comment: @renchie: Milliseconds in a day. Yep, you don't need the `+` when using `-` as the operator :)

Comment: @frenchie - I think William Van Rensselaer's answer is better - just set the date to zero and you get the last day of the previous month.

Comment: @RobG: I agree, I didn't know setting it to `0` would do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var FirstDay = new Date(Year, Month, 1);
var lastMonth = new Date(FirstDay);
lastMonth.setDate(-1);
alert(lastMonth);
```

And remember that 8 is Sept, not Aug in JavaScript. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to calculate this based on today's date ( you want the last day of last month ), the following should help.

If you only care about the month/day/year, this is the simplest and fastest that I can think of:

```
var d = new Date(); d.setDate(0);
console.log(d);
```

If you want midnight of last day of the previous month, then:

```
var d = new Date(); d.setDate(0); d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(d);
```

If you want to know the last day of the previous month, based on provided year/month:

```
var year = 2016, month = 11;
var d = new Date(year, (month - 1)); d.setDate(0); d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(d);
```

After running any of the above, to get the YYYY-M-D format:

```
var str = d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d.getDate();
console.log(str);
```

To see additional methods available, and to see what they do, you can [read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype).